# How to add ROS to path in VS Code?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is anyone using VS Code to program in ROS? I kind of like this IDE ( haven't used it earlier ) and want to use it as it comes with a lot of features which I like.

My question is when I `include <ros/ros.h>` it puts a green squiggle below it, and also for service file generated headers it can't really locate them. Any suggestions on how to add on to the path to avoid this.

To be noted, there is no problem in building it as it is already in the path of Linux terminal...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256565/how-to-add-ros-to-path-in-vs-code?/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-10**:
There isn't a section for VS Code on the [ROS IDE wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs), but the instructions for one of the other IDEs might provide some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [IDE wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) now includes an entry for VSCode, which points to a ROS extension. Among other things, this extension will add the appropriate include paths. I tried this and it works nicely.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samarth.robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39083/samarth.robo/) on 2020-12-14**:
If the task provided by the VSCode ROS extension does not work (in my experience that feature is brittle), you might find [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/282295/how-to-setup-intelisense-on-vs-code-for-ros-c/?answer=367723#post-id-367723) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to clyde answer:

1- Open VSCode and (Ctrl+Shift+X) and search for ROS

2- Install ( ROS VSCode Extension )

3- Restart VSCode

4- Make sure to open your workspace ex: file ->openfolder ->catkin_ws

5- The extension will pop up a msg to configure your ROS distro if it cants configure it automatically

6- Also you can use the terminal from VSCode (Ctrl+~) as usual ubuntu terminal

7- Build your catkin workspace at least once from this terminal

8- You can `include <ros/ros.h>`  in your files and you shouldn't see green squiggle below
if everything is configured properly.

9- At the left bottom of VSCode you will find [x ROS Master] that's mean ROS core is not running
try to run $ roscore from the terminal in VSCode and notice [✔ ROS Master]

---

Originally posted by [amer](https://answers.ros.org/users/36047/amer/) with karma: 71 on 2018-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murali1842](https://answers.ros.org/users/26540/murali1842/) on 2018-10-26**:
I am trying with simple talker.cpp program. I could not find a way to RUN it. I have followed all your steps.
When I debug  I get this following error:
Unable to start debugging. Program path '/home/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/talker.cpp' is missing or invalid.

**Comment by [murali1842](https://answers.ros.org/users/26540/murali1842/) on 2018-10-26**:
GDB failed with message: "/home/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/talker.cpp": not in executable format: File format not recognized

**Comment by [murali1842](https://answers.ros.org/users/26540/murali1842/) on 2018-10-26**:
This may occur if the process's executable was changed after the process was started, such as when installing an update. Try re-launching the application or restarting the machine.

**Comment by [murali1842](https://answers.ros.org/users/26540/murali1842/) on 2018-10-26**:
Can you give me some suggestions please...

**Comment by [chrishuynh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54998/chrishuynh/) on 2020-05-17**:
Im sorry but my vscode cannot configure automatically as well as dont pop up the msg to configure ROS distro.
Is there any way to fix this?
Anyone helps me!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For ROS to work completely in Vscode,  without an external plugin.

First. change "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser" for  autocomplete:
[image: image description]

in `.vscode`  folder,  make or change `tasks.json` for build, clean and prepare for debug.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "prerun",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": [
                "build package only"
            ],
            "command": "source ../../devel/setup.bash && export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/ "
        },
        {
            "label": "build all packages",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin config --extend /opt/ros/noetic && catkin build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -j8",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "build package only",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin config --extend /opt/ros/noetic && catkin build ${workspaceFolderBasename} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -j8",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "clean",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin clean --yes"
        },
        {
            "label": "release",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "sudo checkinstall --install=no catkin build -j4 --cmake--args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the file `c_cpp_properties.json` add include files propriety

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/ros/noetic/include/**",
                "~/catkin_ws/devel/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

For debug,  make ou change  `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${env:HOME}/catkin_ws/devel/lib/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "preLaunchTask": "prerun",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true,
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Final result:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Diogo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/40037/diogo42/) with karma: 91 on 2020-11-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8